# Is it possible to have one changelog per database object in Liquibase?

Tags: sql-server, database, liquibase

I'm currently in the process of getting Liquibase setup so I can version-control my database.

However, one thing I've been struggling with is coming up with a decent directory structure. Google has left me with very limited examples, and the Liquibase "Best-practices" change-log structure seems too simple (in the sense that there's one giant change-log per release).

Ideally I'd like to have one change-log per database object. However, I'm not entirely sure this is possible. For example, lets say I first create table A, then table B which has a foreign key back to A, then I create table C. Later on I decide table B needs to have a foreign key to table C. However, how would I handle this in Liquibase? The obvious answer is to just put in a changeset that adds that foreign key constraint after the changesets that have created those tables. However, if I'm doing one changelog per db object, I don't really see a "clean" way without reordering the changelog includes. You can't put that changeset in the table B changelog because table C might not yet exist.

Here's a small illustration showing the process in order of execution:

(master.changelog.xml)

- Create Table A (table.a.changelog.xml)
- Create Table B with FK to A(table.b.changelog.xml)
- Create Table C (table.c.changelog.xml)
- Add FK to C from B (??? can't exist in table.b.changelog.xml)

This issue is compounded if you break up the changelogs by Schema.

Is there a clean way to have one changelog per db-object or is it not really a viable option?

Comment: It's a bit unusual to do that but it's possible. You only need to move the FKs to a separate changelog which will be executed after all tables

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yeah, this is what I figured but it would kind-of defeat the purpose of one change-log per db object.

I guess it would perhaps make more sense to have db-constraints in their own changelogs?

Comment: It certainly is the only way you can do it.

Comment: My preference is to have one main changelog file , whose purpose is to pull in a series of changesets, generated at each increment of the project. It's a more mechanical approach but works better with my workflow.

Comment: What issue are you trying to address by having one changelog per object?

Comment: @SteveDonie, for me, it's easier to see/track changes on specific objects. Especially when using this on top of Mercurial/Git, it's very easy to see the history of how changesets got applied, and what other Liquibase changelogs got added in those mercurial changesets. Perhaps it's personal preference but it seems fairly logical to track changes this way.

Comment: @MarkO'Connor and SteveDonie. I think I'll adopt the one stated in the Liquibase best practices. While the route I was going works, it's definitely more of a hassle.

Comment: @JonathanBastnagel If it's any consolation I initially attempted to do what you were doing and eventually made the same decision, to just track the changes to my schema :-)